# convert an Object to an Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My object is like this (tried with .map, .push, object.assign, object.values - nothing helping).

[image]

And I need to change that object like below how can I do that?
[image]

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just access [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```
data.item3 = Object.values(data.item3)
```

Comment: similar approach worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.item3 = Object.keys(data.item3).map(key => ({...data.item3[key]}))
```

Comment: This would get you [“0”, “1”] - not what OP wanted